# What's the meaning of the Karmin song "Acapella"?

Tags: lyrics, meaning

I heard this Karmin song titled [*Acapella*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KJWJfRAGnHc), but I'm not sure what the meaning of *acapella* is as used in this song.

I've been googling the lyrics and I'm still not sure about the meaning of it. Can anyone explain what it means?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think she may be confused regarding the actual meaning of the phrase "a cappella".  She seems to be using it to state that she will be going solo -  without whomever she's singing about.

"A Cappella" is an old Italian phrase - literally "in the style of chapel".  Originally, it could be used to describe any facet of a church and its procedure.  It made its way into common vernacular in the 19th century, used to describe the style of the purely vocal Cappella Sistina (Sistine Chapel) Choir.  Over time, it came to describe any music without instrumental accompaniment. 
You can certainly do a cappella solo.

Comment: so is that mean in this song, she likes to be "alone" rather than in a relationship?

Comment: Not necessarily that she likes to be alone, she's done with the relationship she's talking about.  But yes, in the context she's using "a cappella" to mean she's leaving the guy and 'going out on her own'. 
It's not proper use of the phrase, but it's not uncommon when writing lyrics to bend meanings a little to make things rhyme and/or fit with the melody.

Comment: a cappella is not literally "in the style of chapel," that's the understood meaning of it. It's literal translation is "to/from chapel/church."

Comment: You are correct, that is not the literal Latin translation.  It's the literal Italian translation:  a cappella - in chapel style  First Known Use: circa 1864